# Match all occurrences of group A followed by two groups B, with padding characters

Tags: php, regex

I have a string with the following "valid" pattern which is repeated multiple times:
A specific group of characters, say "ab", any number of other characters, say "xx", a different specific group of characters, say "cd", any number of other characters, say "xx".

So a valid sequence would be:
"abxcdabxxcdabxcdxx"

I'm trying to detect invalid sequences of this specific form: "abxxcdxxcd", and remove the middle "cd" to make it valid: "abxxxxcd"

I have tried the following regex:

```
/(?<=ab).*(cd).*(?=ab)/gsU
```

It works for a single sequence, but it fails for the following string:
"abxx**cd**xcdxxabxcdxxabx**cd**xxcd", which contains an invalid sequence, followed by a valid sequence, followed by another invalid sequence. I want to capture both groups in bold.

Note that the other characters "xx" may contain anything, including line breaks. They will never, however, contain the strings "ab" or "cd", except in the invalid case I specified.

Here's the corresponding regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/U9pRfo/1

**Edit:**

[Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55187221/4166237) worked out for me. I was however getting PREG_JIT_STACKLIMIT_ERROR in php when using that regex on a very large string. I ended up just splitting that string into smaller chunks and rebuilding the string after, which worked perfectly.

Comment: `(?:\G(?!^)|ab)(?:(?!ab|cd).)*\Kcd(?=(?:(?!ab|cd).)*cd)`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QwnLcS/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, that works! If you post it as an answer and explain what's going on in there, I'll accept it :) As a bonus, I'm getting a PREG_JIT_STACKLIMIT_ERROR when I try the preg_replace on a large string. Is there a more efficient version of this regex that is possible? Otherwise I can probably work around it.

Comment: Also, [here is an optimized version](https://regex101.com/r/QwnLcS/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(?:\G(?!^)|ab)(?:(?!ab).)*?\Kcd(?=(?:(?!ab).)*?cd)~s'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QwnLcS/2)

- `(?:\G(?!^)|ab)` - a nbon-capturing group matching `ab` or the end of the previous match
- `(?:(?!ab).)*?` - matches any char, 0 or more times, as few as possible, that does not start a `ab` char sequence
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `cd` - a substring
- `(?=(?:(?!ab).)*?cd)` - a positive lookahead that requires any char, 0 or more repetitions, as few as possible, that does not start the `ab` char sequence and then `cd` char sequence.